# Received xml content is changed, when I send it to rest api from http request

Tags: java, xml, rest, svg

I am writing program to process svg editor input in java. This is the code i used to send the svg file to my JAXRS rest api.

```
$('#save').click(function (e){
    var svg = canvas.toSVG();
    fabric.log(svg);

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/webapi/svg',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          svg,
        },
        success: function(){alert('PUT completed');}
    });
  });
```

And the svg log as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.3</desc>
<defs></defs>
<line id="branch" x1="-93" y1="84.5" x2="93" y2="-84.5" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 5; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(245 300.5)"/>
<line id="branch" x1="-67" y1="-84" x2="67" y2="84" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 5; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(308 296)"/>
<line id="branch" x1="-103" y1="131.5" x2="103" y2="-131.5" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 5; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(360 269.5)"/>
<line id="branch" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 5; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(524 201)"/>
</svg>
```

And when I post this svg to my rest api it gets as follows.

```
svg=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22+standalone%3D%22no%22+%3F%3E%0A%3C!DOCTYPE+svg+PUBLIC+%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD+SVG+1.1%2F%2FEN%22+%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%0A%3Csvg+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22+xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22+version%3D%221.1%22+width%3D%22800%22+height%3D%22500%22+viewBox%3D%220+0+800+500%22+xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Cdesc%3ECreated+with+Fabric.js+1.6.3%3C%2Fdesc%3E%0A%3Cdefs%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%0A%3Cline+id%3D%22branch%22+x1%3D%22-93%22+y1%3D%2284.5%22+x2%3D%2293%22+y2%3D%22-84.5%22+style%3D%22stroke%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+stroke-width%3A+5%3B+stroke-dasharray%3A+none%3B+stroke-linecap%3A+butt%3B+stroke-linejoin%3A+miter%3B+stroke-miterlimit%3A+10%3B+fill%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+fill-rule%3A+nonzero%3B+opacity%3A+1%3B%22+transform%3D%22translate(245+300.5)%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cline+id%3D%22branch%22+x1%3D%22-67%22+y1%3D%22-84%22+x2%3D%2267%22+y2%3D%2284%22+style%3D%22stroke%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+stroke-width%3A+5%3B+stroke-dasharray%3A+none%3B+stroke-linecap%3A+butt%3B+stroke-linejoin%3A+miter%3B+stroke-miterlimit%3A+10%3B+fill%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+fill-rule%3A+nonzero%3B+opacity%3A+1%3B%22+transform%3D%22translate(308+296)%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cline+id%3D%22branch%22+x1%3D%22-103%22+y1%3D%22131.5%22+x2%3D%22103%22+y2%3D%22-131.5%22+style%3D%22stroke%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+stroke-width%3A+5%3B+stroke-dasharray%3A+none%3B+stroke-linecap%3A+butt%3B+stroke-linejoin%3A+miter%3B+stroke-miterlimit%3A+10%3B+fill%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+fill-rule%3A+nonzero%3B+opacity%3A+1%3B%22+transform%3D%22translate(360+269.5)%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cline+id%3D%22branch%22+x1%3D%220%22+y1%3D%220%22+x2%3D%220%22+y2%3D%220%22+style%3D%22stroke%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+stroke-width%3A+5%3B+stroke-dasharray%3A+none%3B+stroke-linecap%3A+butt%3B+stroke-linejoin%3A+miter%3B+stroke-miterlimit%3A+10%3B+fill%3A+rgb(0%2C0%2C0)%3B+fill-rule%3A+nonzero%3B+opacity%3A+1%3B%22+transform%3D%22translate(524+201)%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

This is my restApi code.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String showModel(String xmlString) {
    System.out.println(xmlString);
    return "Post Method";
}
```

If I tried with rest client and send post request to rest api with above xml content as body, rest api print whole xml content as it is.

If anyone know solution for this problem. Please help me. I want to store xml in a file. But recieved content is encordered or something.

Comment: java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");

Comment: It's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default content-type when using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, and that is why the data is encoded that way.

If you don't want that encoding, change it.

Since you're sending SVG data, specify `contentType: 'image/svg+xml; charset=UTF-8'` in the `$.ajax()` call.

You should also change the handler method to specify `@Consumes("image/svg+xml")`, if you want to limit the handler to only accept SVG data.